# Interesting CSS selector

Tags: html, css

I have an interesting CSS selector here:

```
.gridcell[id="danger"] {
  color: red;
}
```

I think that it should style the paragraph element in the following section:

```
<div class="gridcell" id="danger">
  <p>fort_sumter</p> // this would be styled
</div>
```

However nothing is styled at all. To my understanding, the [] in the selector means that it is searching for something within gridcell that has the id of danger, which would be the p element, but it's not working. Any ideas of the correct html section that would be styled with this block of CSS?

Thanks,

brld

**EDIT: Fixed the weird quotes that were there from Atom.**

Comment: Your quotes are *really* strange... Should really check your quotes. Here's fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/vea0kz00/1/

Comment: You could use hash instead: `#danger { color: red }`

Comment: Use `#danger` to select by id, and `.gridcell` to select by class. Combine by appending, `#danger.gridcell`

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some strange Unicode quote there, specifically code point 8221 "Right Double Quotation Mark". It should be code point 34 "Quotation Mark".

Try to find the difference between the two: U+8221:`”`  U+34`"`.

This could be caused by some interesting system keyboard settings, or if you wrote that CSS in a text processing application (e.g. MS Word, LibreOffice Writer, Google Docs, etc)

With the risk of repeating other answers, the canonical way of selecting by ID in CSS is by using the `#` character, followed by the ID you want to match:

```
.gridcell#danger
```

---

As a stylistic note, since IDs are unique, consider using a more descriptive name, or switch to a class.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting mistake.
Be careful with the characters you use. Instead of ” it's the double-quote character " you have to use.

Change

```
.gridcell[id=”danger”] {
  color: red;
}
```

to

```
.gridcell[id="danger"] {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your selector is using the incorrect type of double quotes. Are you editing your code in a rich text format on a mac computer? Your quotes should be straight, not curly.

Also, you are a bit mistaken about the way to write this selector. To select that paragraph by its class and ID you would write:

```
.gridcell#danger {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only can use .div to class object or #div to id object, if you need select a brother element can use

```
.class #id{    
    /* style */   
}
```